# How do I make Tailwind CSS max-w to work?

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css, width

I used the proper class for setting max width in tailwind and it worked, until it didn't. I don't understand it myself but now the max-w has refused to take effect.

```
<section class="max-w-[80em]"></section>
```

I used this one on a different page before and it worked, suddenly on this new page, it worked and stopped.

I have checked past questions on here but no solution worked for me.

Comment: Please edit your question to include a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that includes all relevant CSS

Comment: "it worked, until it didn't", what do you mean ?

Comment: It seems to work just fine https://play.tailwindcss.com/OdB5pWZGkG

Comment: @BouncyBits it worked until it didn't. Idk what happened, it was fine and then it just stopped

Comment: @Joshua it's tailwind. That's the CSS there

Comment: @theocode, can you product tailwind-playground link, telling about your issue.

Comment: @BouncyBits no I don't know how to do what you just said

Comment: Open my link paste your code click on the share button and share us the link

Comment: @BouncyBits I appreciate that you're trying to help right now, but I don't think you understand my problem, my problem is that some of the tailwind components are no longer working. I'm having to resort to css now, because things like padding, and max width and border radius no longer work

Comment: Are you using dynamic classes? Because it cannot happen the way you said , only possibility is when it is the dynamic class